# Disable left and right swipe in Google Chrome to act as "back" and "forth" in medical device

Tags: google-chrome, navigation

We released a software that has a web interface for the operator (a medical device). The software has a state map regolating the workflow. Machine is provided with a capacitive touch screen.
Is it possible to totally disable the possibility to go "back (previous page)" or "forth (next page)" in Google Chrome? we use this browser as a standard, and we run it automatically at the startup in --kiosk mode and --incognito mode. 
We tryed the –overscroll-history-navigation=0 flag, but it does not work at all. 
We would like to totally ignore history. If the customer succeeded in activating the "back" action, all the state machine goes wrong and the machine stuck. 
found a lot of references about chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation, but it seems it does not exist any more (not in myne)

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but I recommend doing whatever you can to fix "all the state machine goes wrong". It could be as simple as a bit of JavaScript on page load which checks if the wrong page for the state is shown and redirects. This won't solve the unintended navigation entirely, but it will make the system more **robust** overall — for example, while I assume the pages are being served on the same device or an internal LAN, if _somehow_ there is a communication error this will help recovery on reload.